# Android, Espresso: Is one view is under another view?

Tags: android-espresso

I has screen with 3 buttons. The content of screen (3 buttons) is generate by code. So I need to test is button#2 is under button#1. How I can do this by Android Espresso?

Answer (score 0):

I think [PositionAssertions](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/test/espresso/assertion/PositionAssertions.html) will help you.